# How can I link my PHP file to the HTML of a module?

Tags: php, fix-my-code

I have this newsletter module in joomla with this code

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="prova.php"> 
<div class="tm-block-bottom-b tm-block-padding tm-block-primary-dark tm-primary">
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
<section class="tm-bottom-b uk-grid" data-uk-grid-match="{target:'> div > .uk-panel'}" data-uk-grid-margin="">
<div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-width-medium-1-2"><div class="uk-panel uk-text-right tm-text-left-small" style="min-height: 30px;">
<p class="uk-text-large uk-margin-remove tm-form-line-height uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-slide-left" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-slide-left'}">Vuoi <strong>rimanere aggiornato</strong>? Iscriviti alla newsletter</p></div></div>
<div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-width-medium-1-2"><div class="uk-panel" style="min-height: 30px;">
<form class="uk-form uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-slide-right" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-slide-right'}" data-uk-margin="{cls:'uk-margin-top'}"><input class="uk-form-width-medium" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Inserisci la tua mail ..."> <button class="uk-button" type="submit">Invia</button></form></div></div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

And I also have a php file. How do I link the php file to the code in the module to make it work?

Comment: Do use this method. You're using Joomla, which means you should stick to the Joomla methods. Use a module, and a module only

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla, you cannot drop a php script, an Html snippet and just submit information to the script. You are not taking advantage of the whole CMS.

There are several restrictions that route every HTTP request to the main index.php and deliver content through the main component or modules. Thus, your Html snippet is not going to reach the php script.

You could modify the .htaccess to allow direct access to the php script, but *it is highly not recommended*.

For instance, to support a newsletter subscription, you have a great (free) extension like **AcyMailing**.